# How to add a workflow variable to 100 different workflows?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to add a workflow variable `$$ABCD` to 100 different workflows. Is there a way I can achieve it without modifying individual workflows? I want to save some effort here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to mass-edit workflows (or any other objects in PowerCenter). The only way is to export your workflows, edit the XMLs (can be done via script) and import them back.